# 3x AA battery phone charger input voltage drop

Tags: batteries, dc-dc-converter, telephone

I am using a 0.9-5 V to 5 V dc-dc step up converter to charge a phone using 3 AA batteries, but whenever I plug in the phone it starts charging but the input voltage drops from ~4.5 V to less than 2 V and the converter only heats up without really charging the phone even though it lights up as if it is charging. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Use Ohm's Law and get better batteries.  where V, maH and ESR are inversely related

Comment: Please mesure the battery voltage under load. How hot does it get?

Comment: Batteries get warm at best,though voltage is unstable and is changing from 1 V to 3.5 V back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I fix this problem?

Go back to high school physics.

Modern converters give you lots of flexibility in changing one voltage and current combination to another. However, they can't cheat physics and give a higher power out than in. Ultimately, some part of the three links in your chain can't handle the power that the phone requires.  The three links are the batteries, the 5 V supply, and the phone charger.

Since you measured at the output of the 5 V supply and found the voltage collapsed, you know that it's either the batteries or the 5 V supply that can't handle the power.

Comment: The voltage on the output is a stable 5V.The input voltage drops when a load is connected (in this case,a phone).When I connect the input to the usb port of the pc the voltage drops from 5v to ~4,3v.So i'm guessing it's the batteries?Though what could be the problem in them since they are new?

Comment: Your load could be unreasonable, or they could be low quality cells.   I once saw some AAA's (almost certainly fraudulently) bearing a major brand's logo that would read fine with a meter, but collapsed to nothing under even slight load.  Remove the load and they'd quickly go back to a decent voltage.  A whole box of them had ended up in the company supply closet, after someone found a "deal".